# Play sound when connecting to network

Tags: networking, audio

I thought it would be fun to play a sound when connecting to a network of some sort (wireless or otherwise), kind of like the dial-up sounds of yesteryear.

EDIT: Clarification: when connecting to the network, so the sound starts playing when the connection attempt is initiated, and stops when the connection is successfully established

A google doesn't bring up anything obvious..

Any ideas? (I'm willing to [attempt to] write a plugin or something, if someone could point me in the right direction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, if you are using a mechanism such as `/etc/network/interfaces` (in Debian and its derivatives) to bring network interfaces up, you can launch a script with the `pre-up` hook, and kill the script with the `post-up` hook. This script would generate sound continuously, probably by playing a sound file in a loop.

I'm not aware if there is a way to attach commands to more high level systems like Network Manager.

Comment: About the high-level systems, the [Network Manager's DBUS API](http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/developers/api/09/spec.html) has *signals* that you could hook onto ([C example](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/examples/C/glib/monitor-nm-state-GDBus.c); [many more](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/examples/)). That said, your desktop environment might already provide the means for that (e.g. KDE: *System Settings -> Notifications -> Source: Network Mgmt*)

Comment: You can also write a script to go in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`.  See `NetworkManager(8)` for more details.